# D-Link can't find Reddit, opens dlinksearch instead

Tags: dns

When I go to reddit.com, it opens the dlinksearch, seems like my router is not finding the path to reddit. This started right after 2014 ended.
I went to  192.168.0.1 and changed the time config, it worked for a short time period, but I restarted the computer and now it won't work anymore.

## edit

I went berserk and reseted the router to factory settings, it works now, but the solution may have been a little desperate.

Comment: And if you change the time again? You're on to something there, so investigate, Sherlock! ;-)

Comment: Like I said, it won't work anymore.

Comment: What's the model of your router?

Comment: No, you wrote that it worked until you restarted your computer. So, try the same fix again, please. We need much more information, or this question might soon be closed.

Comment: D-Link DIR-615 .

Comment: Arjan, maybe I didn't explained well, sorry for my bad english. I DID tried it, and it didn't work

Comment: I went berserk and reseted the router to factory settings, it works now, but the solution may have been a little desperate.

Comment: Make sure to change router password to something hard to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change [DNS Server](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/dns_domainnamesystem/f/dns_servers.htm) on your router.

these problems often caused by **faulty or old DNS Server**.

I'm using [openDNS](https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/opendns-ip-addresses/) for example and it works just fine.

Comment: Faulty or old or changed by router password-guessing malware. I recommend Google Public DNS: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`. It's plain DNS, without any extra features that some may not like.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this may help you with removing the redirects. http://malwaretips.com/blogs/www1-dlinksearch-com-removal/

Comment: It's not a malware

Comment: How sure are you? You could attempt to either supply more information or try the following methods to check if it is malware.

Comment: Because It's the router page, I didn't though someone would think it's malware because it's kinda obvious... But if you want to make sure, this happens with ANY device connected in the router, even in my Linux computer and Android smartphones.